# Application Insights: HTTP OPTIONS recorded but GET/POST ignored

Tags: angularjs, cookies, cors, azure-application-insights, http-options-method

I'm using AI on an Angular site with a WebAPI backend.

I'm setting the AuthenticatedUserContext and I can see the info being attached as cookies when doing http requests to my API. Because of CORS there is a pre-flight http OPTIONS request and as expected this request does not include the AI cookies.

Looking at the telemetry data in AI I can only see the OPTIONS requests but not the GET/POST request. The session and Authenticated user info is not attached to the OPTIONS request. Why is the OPTIONS request recorded but not the GET/POST? How can I record the GET/POST requests without the OPTIONS requests

﻿

Comment: Either modify the reqeust such that a preflight isn't required, or have the server properly respond to the preflight so that the browser can follow it up with the proper get/post request.

Comment: @KevinB what do you mean by "follow it up with the proper get/post request"? The get/post requests are completed successfully after the pre-flight request, the only issue is they are not recorded in the telemetry in AI.

Comment: I mis-understood then. I was under the impression they weren't happening, which is generally an indication of a cors error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replied to you in msdn forum. Replying here as well:

I think you hit the [bug](https://web.archive.org/web/20200916205457/https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/93). GitHub issue has a workaround suggestion you may try

For filtering use this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling). You'll have code like this:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

public class SuccessfulDependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // Link processors to each other in a chain.
    public SuccessfulDependencyFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (!OKtoSend(item)) { return; }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    private bool OKtoSend (ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as RequestTelemetry;

        //if its not a Request, return true.  We don't care to filter it here
        if (request == null) return true;

        if (request.Name.StartsWith("OPTIONS")) //CORS Pre Flight Request
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```